WDF Driver: Device driver cannot initialize for this hardware. An invalid parameter is passed to a service or function
I am developing a driver based on ACX. I am developing and building it upon the sample Windows provide here ACX audio driver. I have added the support of dynamic enumeration and setup of audio device on top of that.
When I build and install the driver, I see in device manager. it shows an error with code 37.
enter image description here.
It seems to be an issue with some initialization. I also see problem code as 0xC000000D in device details.
enter image description here
Can someone please help me on this if they have faces such issue while developing the driver earlier?
Any help is appreciated.
I tried too see the details and error codes by putting up some logs and found the reason to be related to initaliazation.
